# How to run a RunnableGraph in Akka Streams 2.4.2 and ensure inlets/outlets are configured correctly?

Tags: akka-stream, reactive-streams

I've configured a RunnableGraph using GraphDSL.create(). I've also specified a ClosedShape and connected all outlets/inlets. When I try to execute the program I get the following runtime exception:

`requirement failed: The inlets [] and outlets [] must correspond to the inlets [filter.in] and outlets [out]`

Any idea where I've not correctly connected inlets and outlets?

Here's the graph code:

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
  implicit builder =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    // Source
    val A: Outlet[String] = builder.add(Source.fromIterator(() => flightDelayLines)).out

    // Flows
    val B: FlowShape[String, FlightEvent] = builder.add(csvToFlightEvent)
    val C: FlowShape[FlightEvent, DelayRecord] = builder.add(flightEventToDelayRecord)
    val D: UniformFanOutShape[DelayRecord, DelayRecord] = builder.add(Broadcast[DelayRecord](2))
    val F: FlowShape[DelayRecord, (Int, Int)] = builder.add(countByCarrier)

    // Sinks
    val E: Inlet[Any] = builder.add(Sink.ignore).in
    val G: Inlet[Any] = builder.add(Sink.ignore).in


    // Graph
    A ~> B ~> flightEventToDelayRecord ~> D ~> E
                                          D ~> F ~> G

    ClosedShape
}).run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem. It was a very simple oversight. Rather than use `C` that I added to the builder, I was using the `flightEventToDelayRecord` function in the graph. The solution was to use `C` in the graph instead.

```
// Graph
A ~> B ~> C ~> D ~> E
               D ~> F ~> G
```

This made me realize how important it is to break large graphs into small ones. The runtime exception does not pinpoint root cause (e.g, "C is unused"), so it will likely be easier to debug these runtime exceptions if working with smaller graphs. Hope this helps anyone else who becomes stuck.